# how to update the name attribute of a HTML helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC4, just wondering, is it possible to update the name attribute of a html helper.  I am updating this as the action method is expecting a particular name.  I know I can just write raw html, but just want to know if there is an overide in the html helper

I tried this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.noteDetail.NotesDetails, new { @class = "k-textbox", @cols = 100, @rows = 5, id="NotesDetails", name= "NotesDetails" })
```

but when I look at the generated html

```
<textarea class="k-textbox" cols="100" data-val="true" data-val-required="The details are required" id="NotesDetails" name="noteDetail.NotesDetails" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Thanks

Comment: try "@Name" (uppercase N)

Comment: @JleruOHeP seems like all that would do is create a second, non-standard attribute that differs only in case. It *might* work but I'd still consider it broken.

Comment: @tvanfosson yeah it`s a kind of hack. Because  The whole point of XXXFor operators (like TextAreaFor) is to auto-generate name for a model binding.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a @ symbol in front of your name property.

Comment: The `@` symbol is used to turn an otherwise reserved keyword into a legal variable name. Since `name` isn't a reserved keyword, it's not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

One technique I've found when a submodel is the model that your POST action accepts is to put the HTML that renders the submodel in a partial view that's included in the main view. Have this partial by strongly typed by the submodel and pass the value of the submodel into it. This way, the prefixes won't be generated on the submodel.

```
 @Html.Partial("_NoteDetails", Model.noteDetail)
```

Then in `_NoteDetails.cshtml`

```
@model NoteDetail

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.NoteDetails,
                  new { @class = "k-textbox", cols = 100, rows = 5 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think as you pass a `viewModel` as it contains maybe 2 models that is why you have this name. It does like this for the `Binder` to construct objects from your `Post` or `Get`.
If you change the name then you will maybe perform some custom codes for your binder if you want to pass it again to the controller.